# Font icons do not showing up in top menu, what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: css

on this page icons do not show up in top menu. https://a2hosting.wordwpress.com/wpfixit.php
HTML code `<i class="wpbff wpbff-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
someone can help figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue usually happens when there's a problem with icons fonts loading. I can see in the network panel that a bunch of fonts is failed to be loaded. Check that your icon fonts are correctly uploaded and the paths to them are correct too.

[image: failed fonts loading]

Comment: The links on this page are external and do not load on my server

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have an issue with CORS.
Hope this link helps you
https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/doc/configure-cors-to-resolve-web-font-issues/